# Issue using add_row() and add_sub_row() in Advanced Custom Fields (Pro)

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I'm using some PHP code to add fields into Advanced Custom Fields promgrammatically and it's working perfectly except I'm stuck on one field.

```
add_row('layouts', [
    'acf_fc_layout' => 'background_image_with_content_block',
    'slide_images' => 248,
    'overlay' => 'Blue',
    'include_job_search' => 'No',
    'heading_type' => 'Heading 2',
    'heading' => 'Upload your CV today',
    'content' => 'Upload your CV today, and we will be in touch to help you find your perfect career. Upload your CV today, and we will be in touch to help you find your perfect career.',
], $post_id);
```

I have a Flexible Content field called "Layouts" and within this I have a field called "background_image_with_content_block". My code above is adding fields to that ACF layout.

All of it works, however I have a repeater field called "links" inside this which I would like to be able to add rows too and subsequently data to the fields inside of my "links" repeater.

I have two fields inside my "links" repeater field. One is a "link" type field and the other is a "select" type field. Is there a way to do this?

I've tried this but I don't think I've used it correctly:

```
add_row('layouts', [
    'acf_fc_layout' => 'background_image_with_content_block',
    'slide_images' => 248,
    'overlay' => 'Blue',
    'include_job_search' => 'No',
    'heading_type' => 'Heading 2',
    'heading' => 'Upload your CV today',
    'content' => 'Upload your CV today, and we will be in touch to help you find your perfect career. Upload your CV today, and we will be in touch to help you find your perfect career.',
     add_sub_row('links', [
        'acf_fc_layout' => 'background_image_with_content_block',
        'link_colour' => 'White',
    ], $post_id)
], $post_id);
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Using `add_sub_row` "inside" of the array you are passing to `add_row`, makes really little sense. The return value of that function is a boolean, true or false - so you would be adding _that_ boolean value into your array in that place. You need to do these things separately, one after the other, not try and mangle them both into one. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/add_sub_row/#add-a-new-sub-row-outside-of-a-haverows-loop

Comment: @CBroe thanks for your reply. Do you have a code example that you can send me as I'm unsure on how to merge these together?

Comment: What is not clear about the syntax in the documentation?

Comment: @CBroe I guess it's just the way it's displayed, it's different to what I have so it's difficult for me to understand which field names etc. in relation to my project would go in which places from their documentation

Comment: `staff_members` is the field in their example, and `images` the sub-field.

Comment: @CBroe Where do I put my $post_id as per my example which I need as I'm adding an ACF row from a newly created post?

Comment: The signature of the function is shown on top of the page - `add_sub_row($selector, $value, [$post_id]);`

Comment: @CBroe So how would you add this into my existing code because it doesn't seem to work anywhere I put it as per my original example. This is why perhaps a visual example would be easier for me to work with.